# C++ program using vectors

Tags: c++, vector, multiplication

I'm having difficulties finding the problem here , the program must read a number N and then read 2 vectors with N lenght, multiply each number of the first vector with the relevant number of the second one and substract each of the previous multiplies (example A[0]*B[0] - A[1]*B[1] .... A[N-1]*B[N-1] ) Any replies will be greatly appreciated.
Input values : 3/
               1 2 -3
               /4 -5 -6
Output : -4
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/* Splits string using whitespace as delimeter */
void split_input(vector<double> &vector_values, const string &input)
{
    char delim = ' ';

    stringstream mySstream(input);

    string temp;

    while(getline(mySstream, temp, delim))
    {
        vector_values.push_back(atof(temp.c_str()));
    }
}

double multiply(vector<double> &first_vector, vector<double> &second_vector)
{   
    double result = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < first_vector.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            result = first_vector[i]*second_vector[i];
        }
        else 
        {
            result -= first_vector[i]*second_vector[i];
        }
        cout << result << endl;
    }

    return result;
}


int main()
{
    vector<double> first_vector;
    vector<double> second_vector;
    int num;
    string input_values;

    cout << "Please enter a number: " << endl;
    cin >> num ;

    /* Ignores the endline char from the previous cin */
    cin.ignore(); 

    /* Read first string, split it and store the values in a vector */
    getline(cin, input_values);
    split_input(first_vector, input_values);

    cin.ignore(); 

    /* Read second string, split it and store the values in a vector */
    getline(cin, input_values);
    split_input(second_vector, input_values);


    /* Multiply vectors */
    cout << multiply(first_vector, second_vector) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you would show us what some input and output values are.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `cin.ignore()` after `split_input(first_vector, input_values);`. With `cin.ignore()` the first element of the second vector is alway `0`. Your `main()` should look like this:

```
int main()
{
    vector<double> first_vector;
    vector<double> second_vector;
    int num;
    string input_values;

    cout << "Please enter a number: " << endl;
    cin >> num ;

    /* Ignores the endline char from the previous cin */
    cin.ignore(); 

    /* Read first string, split it and store the values in a vector */
    getline(cin, input_values);
    split_input(first_vector, input_values);

    // following line causes the first element of the second vector to become 0
    // cin.ignore(); 

    /* Read second string, split it and store the values in a vector */
    getline(cin, input_values);
    split_input(second_vector, input_values);


    /* Multiply vectors */
    cout << multiply(first_vector, second_vector) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```